# creating Jenkins job using packer and chef-solo

Tags: jenkins, chef-solo, packer

I wanted to create a job with Jenkins to uses packer.
So, I installed packer plugin, and with the simple task using the shell as a provisioner, Jenkins job works fine.
Then I added chef-solo as a provisioner. The cookbook is inside a machine that already has a Jenkins.
But when I ran the job it said:

```
Started by user anonymous

    Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/chef_packer
    [chef_packer] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/biz.neustar.jenkins.plugins.packer.PackerInstallation/buildhost/packer build /tmp/packer7579428840569422062.json
    [1;32mamazon-ebs output will be in this color.[0m

    1 error(s) occurred:

    * Bad cookbook path '/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/cookbooks/': stat /home/ec2-user/chef-repo/cookbooks/: permission denied
    Finished: FAILURE
    Build step 'Packer' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

I can run this command `/var/lib/jenkins/tools/biz.neustar.jenkins.plugins.packer.PackerInstallation/buildhost/packer build /tmp/packer1007439168008859561.json` inside a mashine and it works fine, but from the jenkins console it gave a permision denied error

- I checked permissions. The cookbook has jenkins:jenkis permission

Comment: Are you really sure about the permissions? Things under `/home/ec2-user` sounds like something that should have ec2-user as owner.

Comment: chef solo command it doesnt work outside jenkins job enviroment. so I fetch cookbook from git and add a job for that. and now it works